# How can I approach the convergence of the following integral?

Tags: real-analysis

The question is that determine whether the following integral converges or not:
$$\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{\ln x}\,dx. $$

I tried to prove it using integration by parts, but I could not get any progress. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: this integral does not converge

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner. Could you elaborate ?

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\ln x$ increases to $\infty$, while $\sin x$ oscillates. You can think of this integral as being the sum of the positive parts and the negative parts, in order. That is, ignoring the finite integral from $2$ to $\pi$, we have that
$$ \begin{align}
\int_\pi^\infty \frac{\sin x}{\ln x} dx &= \sum_{k\geq 0} \bigg( \underbrace{\int_{\pi + 2\pi k}^{2\pi + 2\pi k} \frac{\sin x}{\ln x} dx}_{I_k^-} + \underbrace{\int_{2\pi (k+1)}^{2\pi + 2\pi(k+1)}\frac{\sin x}{\ln x} dx}_{I_k^+}\bigg).
\end{align}$$
Now $I_k^-$ is negative, $I_k^-$ is positive, and you can apply the standard alternating series test to the sum
$$ \sum_{k \geq 0} (I_k^- + I_k^+).$$
There are a few details left to consider, such as showing that $I_k^\pm$ is decreasing (resulting from $\ln x \to \infty$), or showing that the limiting behavior of the integral is well approximated by these summands (since they go to zero, essentially), but this is a good approach.

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

This integral converges, since integration by parts permits to reduce to an absolutely convergent integral:
$$\begin{align}\int_2^\infty\frac{\sin x}{\ln x}\,\mathrm dx&=\left[\frac{-\cos x}{\ln x}\right]_2^\infty+\int_2^\infty\cos x\,\left(\frac1{\ln x}\right)'\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac{\cos2}{\ln2}+\int_2^\infty\cos x\,\left(\frac1{\ln x}\right)'\,\mathrm dx
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}\int_2^\infty\left|\cos x\left(\frac1{\ln x}\right)'\right|\,\mathrm dx&\le\int_2^\infty\left|\left(\frac1{\ln x}\right)'\right|\,\mathrm dx\\
&=-\int_2^\infty\left(\frac1{\ln x}\right)'\,\mathrm dx\\
&=-\left[\frac1{\ln x}\right]_2^\infty\\
&=\frac1{\ln2}<\infty.
\end{align}$$