# Check the convergence of the improper integrals $\int_2^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{\log x} d x$ and $\int_0^{\infty}\left(\sin x^2\right) d x$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Actually, I was solving a multiple select question:

Which of the following improper integral are convergent?

(1) $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} d x$

(2) $\int_2^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{\log x} d x$

(3) $\int_0^{\infty}\left(\sin x^2\right) d x$

(4) $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} d x$

For 1st option, I have seen the convergence of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ using Laplace transforms to get the integral as $\frac{\pi}{2}$,

For 2 nd option, I got $\int_2^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{\log x} d x$ is not absolutely convergent since $\frac{|\sin x|}{\log x} \geq \frac{|\sin x|}{x}$ for $x \geq 2$ and $\int_2^{\infty} \frac{|\sin x|}{x} d x$ diverges, but I couldn't conclude about the convergence,

Despite of the derivation of Fresnel function, How to deal with options 3 using the traditional convergence checking methods like comparison, limit comparison, etc?

For 4 th option, I have a fair inequality $e^{-x^2} < e^{-x}$ for $x>1.$

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: For the third one you can change the variable $t = x^2$. For the fourth one, you can approach the same, or consider series expansion of $e^{-x^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \mathrm{d} x=\int_0^{1}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} \mathrm{d}x +\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \mathrm{d} x\\
> \int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \mathrm{d} x=-\dfrac{\cos x}{x}\Bigg|^{+\infty}_1-\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos x}{x^2} \mathrm{d} x$$
> Since $|\cos x|\le 1$, $\,\,\displaystyle{\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos x}{x^2} \mathrm{d} x}\,\,$ converges by comparison test.

> $$\int_1^{\infty}\left(\sin x^2\right) \mathrm{d} x=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin t}{\sqrt{t}} \mathrm{d} t$$
> Then use integration by parts as in the first integral.

> $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \mathrm{d} x$$
> Since $e^t\geq 1+t \quad \forall t \in [0,+\infty) \implies \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\geq \dfrac{1}{e^{x^2}}$. It follows
> $$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x \leq \int_{0}^\infty  \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Here is the second one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268190/how-can-i-approach-the-convergence-of-the-following-integral?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2):

The second integral can be shown to converge in a variety of ways. In particular, it can be shown to converge by some very general approaches that have broad applicability. (This is also applicable to the first and third integrals).

---

**[Dirichlet test](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3309523/148510) for convergence of an improper integral (under weak conditions)**

Suppose $f:[a,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable on any bounded interval such that $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx $ is bounded for all $b > a$ and that the function  $g:[a,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is monotonically decreasing to zero as $x \to \infty$. Then the improper integral $\int_a^\infty f(x) g(x) \, dx$ is convergent.

In this case $f(x) = \sin x$ and $g(x) = [\log x]^{-1}$ are easily seen to satisfy the conditions for the Dirichlet test.

---

**Cauchy criterion and [second integral mean value theorem](https://planetmath.org/secondintegralmeanvaluetheorem).**

(These are more fundamental results that can be used to prove the Dirichlet test.)

The Cauchy criterion states that the improper integral $\int_a^b h(x) \, dx$ is convergent if and only if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $K \geqslant a$ such that  $\left| \int_\alpha ^\beta h(x) \, dx\right| < \epsilon$ for all $\beta > \alpha > K$.

A special case of the second integral mean value theorem for integrals is if $f:[a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable and $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is non-negative and decreasing, then there exists $\xi \in [a,b]$ such that  $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) \, dx = g(a)\int_a^\xi f(x) \, dx$.

For the problem at hand, we have by the second integral mean value theorem with $f(x) = \sin x$ and $g(x) = [\log x]^{-1}$,

$$\left|\int_\alpha^\beta \frac{\sin x}{\log x} \, dx \right| = \left|\int_\alpha^\beta \frac{\sin x}{\log x} \, dx \right| =\frac{1}{|\log \alpha|}\left|\int_\alpha^\xi \sin x \, dx \right|= \frac{|\cos \alpha - \cos \xi|}{|\log \alpha|}\leqslant \frac{2}{|\log \alpha|}$$

For any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $K$ such that if $\alpha > K$ then $|\log \alpha | = \log \alpha > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$. Hence, with $\beta > \alpha > K$ we have

$$\left|\int_\alpha^\beta \frac{\sin x}{\log x} \, dx \right| < \epsilon,  $$

and the improper integral converges by the Cauchy criterion.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already solved (1) and (4), let us concentrate on the two integrals (2) and (3) of your title.

The convergence of the [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) (3) is equivalent (by change of variable $y=x^2$) to the convergence of $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin y}{\sqrt y}\,\mathrm dy.$

Let us now prove that for any decreasing $C^1$ function $f$ vanishing at infinity, $\int_2^{\infty}f(x)\sin x\,\mathrm dx$ converges. This (applied to $f(x)=\frac1{\ln x}$ or to $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt x}$) will prove the convergence of the  two integrals (2) and (3). The recipe is: integration by parts followed by absolute convergence.

$$\begin{align}\int_2^\infty f(x)\sin x\,\mathrm dx&=\left[-f(x)\cos x\right]_2^\infty+\int_2^\infty f'(x)\cos x\,\mathrm dx\\
&=f(2)\cos2+\int_2^\infty f'(x)\cos x\,\mathrm dx
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}\int_2^\infty|f'(x)\cos x|\,\mathrm dx&\le\int_2^\infty|f'(x)|\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_2^\infty-f'(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\left[-f(x)\right]_2^\infty\\
&=f(2)<\infty.
\end{align}$$